# Grant access to login using Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-applications, authentication, azure-active-directory

I created an application in ASP.NET with Azure AD login. My problem is when I'm trying to login using my company user (User type: Member). I have to mention that I don't have admin access. I successfully created an application in the azure portal. 
The error that I receive when I try to login is :
"AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent."
I know that you may have to grant application permissions, but is there anything that I can do on my end ? Is there another way to do this and grant access to login using company profile ?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 things you could check:

- **Permissions at Azure AD Level**: An Azure AD administrator can restrict users to grant access to apps.
- **Permissions at application level**: Please check the "User Assignment Settings" at the application level. Combined this with the permission above, a user may not be able to access the application.
- **Code**: Please check your code and see if you're doing `prompt=admin_consent` when sending the request to Azure AD for authentication/authorization.
- **Portal**: You can grant consent via the Azure Portal by clicking the *Grant Permissions* button inside the app's blade.